# What is the meaning of this joke? "Judgement day is upon us. The minions of Lucifer walk upon the earth.. Oh, no.. It's merely the Danish"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> Judgement day is upon us. The minions of Lucifer walk upon the earth.. Oh, no.. It's merely the Danish.

Came across this phrase (title) in a history game and I'm not entirely sure what the deeper meaning is.

Could it mean "I want all Danes to die"? And is Lucifer a significant person or something?

Comment: In a "history game" the Danes might be Viking marauders.

Comment: Have you done any research at all on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucifer is just another name for the Devil in the Bible. You can read about Lucifer here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer

This is an attempt to insult the Danish people by comparing them to the Devil's followers ("minions"). It's meant to be humorous and clever, but whether it is or not depends on who the audience is. If the person saying this is serious, then it can be quite offensive to whoever is listening. However, it is common for Europeans to insult other Europeans without being completely serious about it.